# kendo dropdown list taking long time to load the options

Tags: performance, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I am developing a kendo grid in my HTML page (not MVC app) and it gets about 500+ records from the backend service. I have 4 Kendo dropdown lists in each row and 2 are getting values from local variables and other 2 are getting data from ajax calls.

When I try to edit any dropdown list, it goes to the editor function of the column, but takes long time to show the values in dropdown list and sometimes the IE page crashes. I am using IE11.

Do you have any best practices to work with Kendo dropdown list type if the grid has more records say > 200 records.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to show that many results in a dropdown list I usually create an autocomplete combobox instead. You can show, for example, 10 results and have the server return more results as the user types.